# integration by parts resulting in a difficult integration?

Tags: integration

If you use apply integration by parts on a product, then you still need to integrate another product, only you hope that this one is easier. But what if it isn't?

Do you then keep on using integration by parts on it until it's solvable?

Answer (score 1):

Typically I would say you do not keep going. If integration by parts leads you to an integral that is no easier than the one you started with, then you probably made a poor choice of $u$ and $v^\prime$. In that case, you might try making a different choice. Or it might be that there is no good choice, and integrating by parts is not the right approach. In that case you might try making a substitution, manipulating the integrand, or consulting a table of integrals or computer (such as Mathematica or http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp).

There are times when a "bad" attempt leads to insight. For example, consider $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty{e^{-x^2}\,dx}\,.$$ Let us try integration by parts with $u = e^{-x^2}$ and $v^\prime = 1$. Then we get

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty{e^{-x^2}\,dx} = 2\int_{-\infty}^\infty{x^2\,e^{-x^2}\,dx}\,.$$

The resulting integral is harder than the one we started with. However, the integral we started with is pretty well known as $\sqrt{\pi}$. So we have actually managed to express the harder integral in terms of a known one: $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty{x^2\,e^{-x^2}\,dx} = {\sqrt{\pi}\over 2}\,.$$

Another example: Suppose you have to evaluate $\int{e^x\,\cos x\,dx}$. If you put $u = e^x$ and $v^\prime = \cos x$, integration by parts gives $$\int{e^x\,\cos x\,dx} = e^x\,\sin x - \int{e^x\,\sin x\,dx}\,.$$ The integral at right is no easier than the one we started with. But let's soldier on. Let $u = e^x$ and $v^\prime = \sin x$. Then the above equation becomes
$$\int{e^x\,\cos x\,dx} = e^x\,\sin x - \left(-e^x\,\cos x + \int{e^x\,\cos x\,dx}\right)\,.$$ Or in other words, with $I$ denoting the original integral we wanted to find, $$I = e^x\,\sin x + e^x\,\cos x - I\,.$$ Solving this gives $I$ up to an overall constant: $$I = {1\over 2}e^x(\cos x + \sin x)\,.$$

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Usually, in Calculus 1 courses, either you picked the wrong way to decompose the integral (that is, $\int u dv = uv - \int v du$ and you picked $u,v$ badly), or you need to get something that looks like the original integral after applying integration by parts a few times - this is often the case when $v$ is a sine or cosine (or sometimes, when $u$ or $v$ are exponential). There is also the tabular method which is useful for cases where you have to repeatedly apply integration by parts (such as when $u = x^n$). Or, you just screwed up your algebra.

Finally, most integrals are just not nice - it is very easy to write down an integral without a closed form. Or, you may need to use a different technique (such as a substitution) which may simplify integration by parts or not require it. While differentiation is mostly mechanical, integration is more of an art form.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if you continue integrating you go on in an infinite loop. The classic example is:
$$\int \sec^3 x \ dx$$
You can use integration by parts.
$$dv=\sec^2 x \ dx$$
$$v=\tan x$$
$$u=\sec x$$
$$du=\sec x \tan x \ dx$$
Integration by parts formula:
$$\int u \ dv = uv - \int v \ du$$
$$\sec x \tan x - \int \tan x \sec x \tan x \ dx$$
$$\sec x \tan x - \int \tan^2 x \sec x \ dx$$
$$\sec x \tan x - \int \sec x \left(\sec^2 x -1\right) \ dx$$
$$\sec x \tan x - \int \sec^3 x - \sec x \ dx$$
$$\sec x \tan x + \int \sec x \ dx - \int \sec^3 x \ dx$$
$$\sec x \tan x + \ln\left|\sec x + \tan x\right| - \int \sec^3 x \ dx$$
If you keep on integrating you will go in an infinite loop. The trick here is to remember that:
$$\int \sec^3 x \ dx= \sec x \tan x + \ln\left|\sec x + \tan x\right| -\int sec^3 x$$
$$2\int \sec^3 x \ dx= \sec x \tan x + \ln\left|\sec x + \tan x\right|$$
$$\int \sec^3 x \ dx= \frac{\sec x \tan x + \ln\left|\sec x + \tan x\right|}{2}$$

---

USUALLY when doing integration by parts I follow the LIATE rule:

L - Logarithmic functions (e.g. $\ln x$)
I - Inverse trigonometric functions (e.g. $\sin^{-1} x$)
A - Algebraic functions (e.g. $x^3$)
T - Trigonometric functions (e.g. $\tan x$)
E - Exponential functions (e.g. $3^x$)

The LIATE rule works most of the time, but there will always be some exceptions. Here is a Wikipedia article on Integration By Parts: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#LIATE_rule

Hope I helped.